# Get time with leading zeroes

Tags: objective-c, ios

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317320/getting-current-time) is my previous question about using date in objective-c. How to get hours, minutes and seconds with leading zeroes ?

Comment: Can you provide an example? do you want to get them as strings or integers?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317320/getting-current-time

Comment: Why my question is down voted ?

Comment: downed (i didn't personally, but have no issue with anyone who did) because you've made those who are here to help you chase links instead of doing the work yourself of transcribing?  or because you duplicated a question that already existed? because you haven't offered what you've tried to do? i suggest you read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now that you precised that you want hours, minutes and seconds as strings, here is how to get them:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]]; 

NSInteger hour= [components hour];   
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
NSInteger second = [components second];

NSString *hourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", hour];
NSString *minuteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", minute];
NSString *secondString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", second];
```

The key is to use `"%02d"` when formatting, to guarantee that you get two digits.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want to format your “date” into a string, and you want leading zeroes in the string.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to access hours, minutes and seconds separately in my code.

Comment: Yes. And you can get the current date by **NSDate *date = [NSDate date];**