# In Objective-C, to get the current hour and minute as integers, we need to use NSDateComponents and NSCalendar?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'd like to get the current hour and minute as integers.  So if right now is 3:16am, I'd like to get the two integers: 3 and 16.

But it looks like `[NSDate date]` will give the number of seconds since 1970, or it can give a string of the current time representation, but there is no easy way to get them as integers?

I see a post in [Getting current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317320/getting-current-time), but it involved `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`?  That's way too complicated... all that was need is something like

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
int hour = [date getHour];     // which is not possible
```

Is there a simpler way than using 3 classes `NSDate`, `NSDateComponents`, and `NSCalendar` to get the current hour as an integer, or typically, in Objective-C, would we typically still use C language's `localtime` and `tm` to get the hour as an integer?

Comment: I checked the reference, and I think there is no other way around this. NSDate seems to be just the number of seconds.

Comment: You could add a catalog on NSDate and extend it to calculate the getHour by using some seconds to date calculations, are you willing to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSDate` just holds the time that has passed since a certain reference date, to get more *meaningful* numbers out of this (eg. after taking care of DST, leap years and all the other stupid time stuff), you have to use `NSDateComponents` with the appropriate `NSCalendar`.

Comment: To put it another way, an `NSDate` references a moment in time. That moment may be known as 3:16am where you are, but the same moment may be known as 6:16pm or even 12:46am someplace else. There is nothing about the moment *alone* which corresponds to "3:16am", you have to specify a time zone and a calendar, too.

Comment: that's true... or if it can be `NSDateComponents dateComponents = [NSDateComponents forLocalTime]`

Comment: At first I thought Calendar is like a monthly calendar / appointment kind of class, but turns out it is for "calendar for different cultures" (11 different calendar system as of right now)... so it is quite profound and useful... maybe there can be a convenience method for the most often used calendar system for NSDateComponents, but I suppose once you are familiar all 3 classes, they are quite powerful

Comment: @user523234 Yup, KenThomases explanation is **way** better! A shame that he won't get any reputation for the comment.

Answer (score 17):

How you interpret the seconds since 1970 depends on the calendar that you are using.  There is simply no other option.  Fortunately it is not that difficult to set up.  See the 'Data and Time Programming Guide' for lots of examples.  In your case:

```
// Assume you have a 'date'
NSCalendar *gregorianCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [gregorianCal components: (NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit)
                                              fromDate: date];
// Then use it
[dateComps minute];
[dateComps hour];
```

So it really isn't that complicated.

Also note that you could create a 'Class Category' to encapsulate this as:

```
 @interface NSDate (MyGregorianDateComponents)
  - (NSInteger) getGregorianHour;
  - (NSInteger) getGregorianMinute;
  @end
```

Comment: Read the question again. There is a link.

Answer (score 1):

My class can help.
https://github.com/TjeerdVurig/Vurig-Calendar/blob/master/Vurig%20Calendar/NSDate%2Bconvenience.m

I'm sure you can figure out the minute part :)

Comment: by the way, later on it seems that NSDateComponents wanted the bit flags so that it can give the required data by a one-time calculation, instead of calculate everything once for the hour, and then calculate all over again for the minute

Comment: Yes I agree that would be better for this situation