# how to get hour with date format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a time format like this

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
```

from this, I need only HH value.

How to get that value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861433/in-objective-c-to-get-the-current-hour-and-minute-as-integers-we-need-to-use-n visit this

Comment: Wow... `HH:mm:ss` gives `12:45:32`, you need only `HH`... don't tell me you've searched for more than 4 seconds before posting this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH";


NSString *datestringofHour= [timeFormatter stringFromDate: localDate];
```

Now in `datestringofHour` variable you will have hour value as a string.

Another one as follows which can give you hour,minute,seconds in integer value

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]]; 

NSInteger hour= [components hour];   
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
NSInteger second = [components second];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just switch:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
```

to:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"HH"];
```